# Firebase Analytics with FCM and DAU

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I saw an strange behavior when I sent a massive push notification to my users. My DAU increased almost 40%, but my push do not sent user to app.
I wanna know when user receive a push notification, it counts on daily active users? And if was some documentation about this, because i couldn't found.

Answer (score 0):

FCM need to start your application in background in order to display the notification.

So yes, it's possible that just receiving the notification counts as DAU.

Comment: So, I need to be sure if counts or not. I know that is possible and other trackers have this behavior, but I need to understand firebase to explain my numbers.
Just to help the others, I considered that counts.